# How to ignore @SneakyThrows of Lombok in Jacoco code coverage?

Tags: java, spring, code-coverage, lombok, jacoco

I use JaCOCO to see code coverage (and use the Intellij plugin for it). I have @SneakyThrows of lombok on my code. Since @SneakyThrows does nothing but converting a checked exception to a unchecked exception, I hope it does not affect the code coverage.

However, it seems that it drops the code coverage:

[image]

I have tried to add `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true` to my `lombok.config`, but no use.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: the thing is - it rather complicated to see in the jacoco report what _exactly_ is not covered when using `lombok` annotations. what I usually do is "de-lombok" everything, run the tests and find out the actual un-covered paths. then "lombok" the code back. there are intellij plugins for that.

Comment: @Eugene I know the code generated by sneaky throws is *not* run. the code is just `... } catch(...) { throw ...}`. Of course it is not run, since I do not cause the code inside to throw. But I want to ignore this un-covered block of `catch`

Comment: you can't. jacoco looks at the `.class` file, that is generated _after_ lombok processor. think about it: you _do_ have a path that is not covered.

Comment: @Eugene hmm... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ignore a certain code path, jacoco has no support for that (neither it can ignore a method). Its unit of measure, for a lack of better term, is a `.class` file. Since jacoco looks at the `.class` file, that is generated *after* lombok processor kicks in, for it - you simply have path that is un-tested.

In simpler words, `jacoco` sees your file like it never had lombok annotations. So you can't "exclude" an annotation. I feel your pain - we have modules where people have enforced a very high number of coverage, and these catch blocks are un-tested, almost all the time.

Comment: Thanks! So is there any ways to work around this? For example, is there alternative tool other than jacoco?

Comment: @ch271828n there is `codecov` for example, it's commercial though, afaik; and I have personally never used it. sonarqube might have something like this too

Comment: I know those tools, but they seem not to provide such kind of things. thanks all the same!

Answer (score 5):

Adding `@Generated` with `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true` will only work for Lombok annotations that generate whole methods. However, `@SneakyThrows` will only add a `try-catch` block around the code inside of the annotated method.

For example if you have following method and want to sneaky-throw the `InterruptedException` from `Thread::sleep`:

```
package com.example;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;

public class Example {

  @SneakyThrows
  public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println("This method does a few things");
    System.out.println("Like counting to 10");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("And waiting a second");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

The generated code would look like this:

```
package com.example;

public class Example {

  public void someMethod() {
    try {
      System.out.println("This method does a few things");
      System.out.println("Like counting to 10");

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }

      System.out.println("And waiting a second");
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

You actually only want to ignore the `try-catch` in the coverage check, not the whole method, so if Lombok added `@Generated` to the whole method you will ignore more coverage than intended.

What you could do, is extracting the code that throws a checked exception to a new method and add both `@Generated` and `@SneakyThrows`.

```
package com.example;

import lombok.Generated;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

public class Example {

  public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println("This method does a few things");
    System.out.println("Like counting to 10");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("And waiting a second");
    waitOneSecond();
  }
  
  @Generated
  @SneakyThrows
  private void waitOneSecond() {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution on this is to attempt to mock `objectMapper` to throw an unchecked exception(eg: RuntimeException) then the code flow will jump inside to catch block(generated by Lombok) and @SneakyThrows will be covered.